How to add a header to a request for a large binary
I can't believe I have to ask this, but here we are. This sounds like the most trivial of requirements, yet it seems mind bogglingly impossible. But I'm not a front end developer so I'm hopefully just missing something obvious.
I have an endpoint that serves a large binary. The browser should download it like normal. But, the endpoint is expecting an Authorization header, as is common these days.
My investigations revealed the following (equally awful) options:

Change the server not to expect the Authorization and replace it with a cookie or something. This is a non starter for a thousand reasons, so lets just move on.
Abandon normal synchronous browser requests and use fetch or similar, and then buffer the gigantic file like a caveman who doesn't understand that RAM and browser storage are limited.
Reimplement half a browser inside a browser using something like native-file-system-adapter or StreamSaver which are intended for client side generated files, and have no business in a regular file download

Is that really it?
